# Pass parameters to a maven mojo invoked programmatically

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

Here I have my Maven Mojo:

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.*;

import java.util.Collections;

@Mojo(name = "run")
public class RunMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
        request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("myplugin:mygoal"));
        
        // need to set parameters to pass to the goal
    
        Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
        try {
            invoker.execute(request);
        } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to invoke a second Mojo passing some parameters as I do when defining the plugin inside the pom.xml, as follow.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>myPlugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
            <version>myVersion</version>
            <configuration>
                <param1>value1</param1>
                <param2>value2</param2>
                <param3>value3</param3>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any solution?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Or which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm developing a plugin which manages the build and the deployment of a java application on a wildfly server(through widlfly-maven-plugin). At some point I need to call the widlfly-maven-plugin in order to start the server, but I also need to pass all the configuration properties to it.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an older question, but found myself in this situation recently and taught I'd show how I created a new plugin where which wraps another plugin.

I've ended up using the mojo-executor plugin (https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) . Even though it is not actively maintained, it does the job quite well. Here is an example of how I executed the html2pdf-maven-plugin (https://bitbucket.org/prunge/html2pdf-maven-plugin/wiki/Home) from my own maven plugin.

The generatePdf(...) method is called from the execute() method of your Mojo class. The getMvnPlugin(...) method is where I specified the plugin groupId and ArtifactId and the execution details. The getPluginConfiguration(...) method is where the plugin configuration is made, specifying the parameters of the html2pdf-maven-plugin.

```
 private void generatePdf(File inputFilePath, String outputFile) {
    String inputDirectory = inputFilePath.getParent();
    String inputFileName = inputFilePath.getName();

    try {
        Plugin html2pdfPlugin = getMvnPlugin(outputFile, inputFile, inputFileName);

        MojoExecutor.ExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment = MojoExecutor.executionEnvironment(mavenProject, mavenSession, pluginManager);
        MojoExecutor.executeMojo(html2pdfPlugin, "html2pdf", getPluginConfiguration(outputFile, inputDirectory, inputFileName), executionEnvironment);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String errorMessage = String.format("Failed to generate PDF file [%s] from html file [%s].", outputFile, inputFile);
        getLog().error(errorMessage, ex);
    }
}

private Plugin getMvnPlugin(String outputFile, String inputDirectory, String inputFileName) {
    Plugin plugin = new Plugin();

    plugin.setGroupId("au.net.causal.maven.plugins");
    plugin.setArtifactId("html2pdf-maven-plugin");
    plugin.setVersion("2.0");

    PluginExecution pluginExecution = new PluginExecution();
    pluginExecution.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("html2pdf"));
    pluginExecution.setId("generate-pdf");
    pluginExecution.setPhase("generate-resources");
    plugin.setExecutions(Collections.singletonList(pluginExecution));

    plugin.setConfiguration(getPluginConfiguration(outputFile, inputDirectory, inputFileName));

    return plugin;
}

private Xpp3Dom getPluginConfiguration(String outputFile, String inputDirectory, String inputFileName) {
    MojoExecutor.Element outputFileElement = new MojoExecutor.Element("outputFile", outputFile);

    MojoExecutor.Element includeElement = new MojoExecutor.Element("include", "**/" + inputFileName);
    MojoExecutor.Element includesElement = new MojoExecutor.Element("includes", includeElement);
    MojoExecutor.Element directoryElement = new MojoExecutor.Element("directory", inputDirectory);
    MojoExecutor.Element htmlFileSetElement = new MojoExecutor.Element("htmlFileSet", directoryElement, includesElement);
    MojoExecutor.Element htmlFileSetsElement = new MojoExecutor.Element("htmlFileSets", htmlFileSetElement);

    return MojoExecutor.configuration(outputFileElement, htmlFileSetsElement);
}
```

The mavenProject, mavenSession and pluginManager just have to be injected in the Mojo class using the org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component.

```
@Component
private MavenProject mavenProject;

@Component
private MavenSession mavenSession;

@Component
private BuildPluginManager pluginManager;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Finally I avoided to wrap the plugin. Anyway, your solution seems the cleanest when you need to wrap another plugin. Apparently, there's no way to accomplish it using the Maven API, instead of relying on third-party libraries (mojo-executor in this case)